# Getting PNG image from geoserver with centered feature

Tags: geoserver, wms, png

I want get PNG image from geoserver, there will be centered feature.
Problem is bounding box.

How get i extent one feature from wms layer? I use cql_filter for select one feature.

One solution is calculate bbox from geometry, scale and sizes image (point layer).

There is a better result, some like "getExtent" parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WMS provides no such feature, but you can use eithe:

- WMS GetFeatureInfo in GML/JSON format, if you know the row/col position where to make the GetFeaturInfo call (it's an info tool, you need to provide the position of the pixel to be queried in the map)
- WFS with the CQL filter to get back the GML/JSON of the feature
- WPS with the Bounds process, which unlike the others, can be used to just return the bounds